# Replace the line number display by a string in Vim

Tags: vim

I want to create a plugin or a piece of code in my vimrc to use vim as a DNA sequence viewer. For this, I need to display permanently a name of a line.

For example:

```
String1  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
String2  BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
String3  CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

`String1`, `String2` and `String3` must be replaced with the line number in vim, for example `String543` if the line is on line 543 of the file.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

See the help for the [`statusline` option](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27statusline%27).

You would probably want to use a status line field like:

```
%{substitute(getline(".")," .*","","")}
```

which displays the first space-delimited word of the current line.
(Don't forget to escape  and `"` when setting it.)

Answer (score 0):

The [ShowMarks.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=152) comes 'close' - if you like

It will show the location of markers inside you file:

[image]

- Use this with [`mksession`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#:mksession) and [`viminfo`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#viminfo-file) to persist markers across restarts.
- You can produce a list of marks using :marks:

  ```
  mark line  col file/text
   '     13   29 cout << std::boolalpha << b << endl;
   a     11    0 smatch m;
   b     13    0 cout << std::boolalpha << b << endl;
   c     16    0 cout << m[0] << endl;
   q     20    0 }
   M      4    0 using namespace std;
   6      8    0 
   "      5    0 
   [      1    0 #include <regex>
   ]     20 2147483647 }
   ^     13   30 cout << std::boolalpha << b << endl;
   .     18    0 cout << endl;
   <     18    0 cout << endl;
   >     18    0 cout << endl;
  ```